# PHP inserting into database - complicated

Tags: php, sql, loops, phpmyadmin

I am trying to insert some values into a database from a form submitted by the user.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();//Gets ID of last value inserted into related table
foreach( $_POST[ 'equipment' ] as $checkBoxIndex => $checkBoxValue ) {

mysql_query("INSERT INTO recipeequipment (recipeid, equipmentid, datetimeentered) VALUES('".$id."', '".$checkBoxValue."', '".$datetime."')");

}
```

The only thing that needs adding to this insert statement is the quantity, which is held in a similar fashion to the checkboxes, but in textboxes. like this:

```
<?php while($rowequipment = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlequipment)) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" value="'.$rowequipment['equipmentid'].'"/>
      <input type="text" name="count[]" id="count[]" size="3" value="" />'
     .$rowequipment['description']."<br />";
      }?>
```

The piece i need help with is the second input column. I need to put the values that correspond with the check boxes into the insert statement, but am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: I will recommend to read about sql injections

Comment: Nice SQL injection holes. Mind if I drive this digital truck thrhough them into your site and do some donuts on your server?

Comment: Why checkboxes at all? Why can't you use text fields only?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on SQL injections and also OOP with PHP.

Comment: Yes ofcourse i will be mysql_real_escape_string() the inputs but i am just trying to find out how to get the quantity. If i use a foreach loop for the text fields as i have done above i will get every field even the empty ones.

Comment: The `id` attribute in HTML should not have an array suffix (square brackets `[]`).  Also, there are a ton of SQL injection holes and XSS vulnerabilities in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring all the vunrabilities in your code for now, doing something like this should allow you to get a unique id and match the checkbox up to the input:

```
<?php while($rowequipment = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlequipment)) {
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="equipment['.$rowequipment['equipmentid'].']" value="'.$rowequipment['equipmentid'].'"/>
      <input type="text" name="count['.$rowequipment['equipmentid'].']" id="count-'.$rowequipment['equipmentid'].'" size="3" value="" />'
     .$rowequipment['description']."<br />";
      }?>
```

Then once that form is submitted you would simply loop through each checkbox by doing  something like:

```
foreach ($_POST['equipment'] as $id => $checkboxValue) {
  $textInputValue = $_POST['count'][$id];
  // do something with the above value here
}
```

Although, I'm not quite sure why you're using checkboxes like this - is it so you ignore updating the rows that they don't check off or something?